# Using Mitre's AttackCTI, How Do I Iterate A List To Output Desired Results

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-lab, mitre-attck

This is a really basic thing I'm asking and I apologize in advance for my novice. I am using Python and JupyterLab to interact with Mitre's Attack Framework (AttackCTI). I want to insert a custom set of attack TECHNIQUES and get a return of the associated attack TACTICS. I assume my problem isn't specific to JL or the AttackCTI, but rather, a lack of skill in Python.

To be honest, I'm not even sure what the last bit of this code is even doing. It's probably not even necessary for what I'm trying to do. I'm very lost, frustrated and inexperienced. I thank you for your patience.

Please help, if you can.

```
from attackcti import attack_client
from pandas import *
import json
import logging
logging.getLogger('taxii2client').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
lift = attack_client()
enterprise_techniques = lift.get_enterprise_techniques()
techniques = []
for t in enterprise_techniques:
    techniques.append(json.loads(t.serialize()))
df = pandas.json_normalize(techniques)
df.reindex(['name'], axis=1)[0:5]
```